upload file to akamai with file name not work
I am trying to upload a file to akamai.
The file name is empty even if I try to concatenate the name to routing
The file was uploaded properly but when I check the file name I have an empty name. So if I upload several files to the same directory I only have one file because all the names of the files I upload are empty names and they replace the previous file that was in the same place.
How can I upload a file to akamai and change the name?
I try to do it in the navigation: http://example-nsu.akamaihd.net/foldername/filename.fileextension and I get a 403 status.
If I upload with such routing to Dodge: http://example-nsu.akamaihd.net/foldername/filename.fileextension/ it creates a new file for me called filename.fileextension and the file I have for this navigation has an empty name.
How to solve it?
